# grails PreUpdateEventListener infinite loop

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have PreUpdateEventListener in my application. It looks like:

```
public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
  if (!needClasses.contains(entity?.class?.name))
   return false

  def entity = event.entity
  boolean rez = false
  entity.withSession {org.hibernate.Session session -> 
    def tryFind = Book.executeQuery("select s.id from ${entity.class.name} s where s.id=? ".toString(), [entity.id])
    rez = (tryFind != null && tryFind.size() > 0)
  } 

  return !rez
}
```

while executing Book.executeQuery it call onPreUpdate again, goes to this line and so on. finally it crash with stack overflow exception by this infinite self calling. 
can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the entity is different then an instance of Book ?

Try using findAll() method instead of executeQuery.

```
Book.findAll("From ${entity.class.name} s where s.id=? ", [entity.id])
//OR this is same as above
def exist = entity.class.get(entity.id)
```

If the entity can be of different type then Book, instead of calling findAll on the Book class you should call it on proper class.

First try using findAll, I guess it would fix your issue.

Comment: I can't use get method, because it works without hibernate filters. entity.class.findAll does not help

Comment: @17dufa so are you getting same issue with findAll too ?